# Why do some of my programs get terminated when the screensaver runs?

Tags: screensaver

I have Mac with OS X 10.6.6 running.

When the screensaver gets started and runs for a few minutes (10 or 15?)
Thunderbind, Firefox and a few other programs gets terminated because
OS X seems to want to log me out.
This is very annoying as I have to restart all of these programs again and again.

The interesting part is I have another Mac also running OS X 10.6.6
where I do not experience this behaviour.

Any help is appreciated

Robert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the Security pane of System Preferences.

Uncheck the box that says, "Log out after [##] minutes of inactivity."